# Bash using "?" as a parameter to call help function

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, parameters

I am trying to use "-help" or "?" as a parameter to call my help function. My code looks like this:

```
#Variablen deklarieren
declare +a source_dir="$1" 
declare +a target_dir="$2"


#Aufruf help-function
if [ "$1" = "?" ] || [ "$1" = "-help" ] ; then
    help_function
    exit 0
fi
```

Calling my script with -help returns the help function, but I have problems using "?" as a parameter.

Comment: What problems exactly? `?` is a glob character ("any character") and is subject to filename expansion.

Comment: Also, `declare +a` is not necessary and quite unusual, I would just drop it.

Comment: `\?` to avoid shell expansion.

Comment: When I type in: bash script.sh ? it isn't printing my helpfunction

Comment: my teacher wants "?" as a parameter :D

Comment: The script should be executed as `script '?'` then, with the question mark quoted. When it's unquoted it's a wildcard and the shell may substitute it for a file name. There's nothing you can do inside your script to prevent wildcard expansion. Linux commands don't usually take `?` as an argument because it's annoying for users to type it.

Comment: @JohnKugelman also doesn't return the help function. I tried it on a different shell and it worked

Comment: When I run this in a directory that has no single character files, this works for me.

Comment: @ExeSiExAqua, do you have any files with 1-character names in your current directory?

Comment: @ExeSiExAqua : The script is fine in the way you posted i. Put a `set -x` on top and call it as `script '?'``, as John Kugelman said, or equivalently as `script \?`. If your help function is still not invoked, you will see from the trace where the problem is.

Comment: Why risk something that is not standard?  Ok on Windows (CMD)  but on linux, I have never seen `?` used as an argument.  Do not reinvent standards.  As for your teacher, it might be something to make you practice, but it is stupid IMHO to do that.  You have much more other things to learn then that bs.